# Open URL using python requests only then proceed to download file

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to download a file from a website using Python's request module.

However the site will allow me to download the file only if the download link is clicked directly from the download page. 
So using requests, I tried hitting the download page's URL first using `requests.get()` then proceeding to download the file. But unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. A text asking me to open the download page first simply gets written into file.torrent"

```
import requests

def download(username, password):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.post('https://website.net/forum/login.php', data={'login_username': username, 'login_password': password})

        # Download page URL
        requests.get('https://website.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2508126')

        # The download URL itself
        response = requests.get('https://website.net/forum/dl.php?t=2508126')

        with open('file.torrent', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)

download(username='XXXXX', password='YYYYY')
```

Response when downloading directly from the download page (works) :

```
General :
Request URL: https://website.net/forum/dl.php?t=2508126
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 185.37.128.136:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers :
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="[website.net].t2508126.torrent"
Content-Length: 33641
Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent; name="[website.net].t2508126.torrent"
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 07:57:08 GMT
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 07:57:09 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: bb_dl=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/forum/; domain=.website.net

Request Headers :
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: bb_t=a%3A3%3A%7Bi%3A2507902%3Bi%3A1550052944%3Bi%3A2508011%3Bi%3A1550120230%3Bi%3A2508126%3Bi%3A1550125516%3B%7D; bb_data=1-27969311-wXVPJGcedLE1I2mM9H0u-3106784170-1550128652-1550131012-3061288864-1; bb_dl=2508126
Host: website.net
Referer: https://website.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2508126
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3701.0 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters :
t: 2508126
```

Response when opening the download link on it's own (doesn't work) :

```
General :
Request URL: https://website.net/forum/dl.php?t=2508126
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 185.37.128.136:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers :
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 08:03:29 GMT
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 08:03:29 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Request Headers :
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: bb_t=a%3A3%3A%7Bi%3A2507902%3Bi%3A1550052944%3Bi%3A2508011%3Bi%3A1550120230%3Bi%3A2508126%3Bi%3A1550125516%3B%7D; bb_data=1-27969311-wXVPJGcedLE1I2mM9H0u-3106784170-1550128652-1550131390-3061288864-1
Host: website.net
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3701.0 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters :
t: 2508126
```

Comment: What is special about the request made by the click on the link? Check your browsers development tools to see the details of the request.

Comment: @Lutz Thanks for replying, I've edited my question to include the responses.

Comment: Remember to update the question or post your own answer after you've done what Lutz Horn said.

Comment: Try to add the `Referer: https://website.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2508126` header to your request. (Just guessing)

Comment: I tried adding 
`headers = {'Referer': 'https://website.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2508126'}
response = requests.get('https://website.net/forum/dl.php?t=2508126', headers=headers)` doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: It will because of cookies I think!

Comment: Change requests.get to session.get in two places to use sessions properly

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
data={'login_username': username, 'login_password': password, 'login': ''}
```

and using `session.get()` instead of `requests.get()`